# Why do I get this .NET error - "TypeError: expected List[DataPoint], got List[DataPoint]"

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime, typeerror

I refactored some code, and now I get this error when calling a function. But everything seems to be fine, I even compared `failing_argument.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` between the old and the new code and they are the same. Any ideas what could be wrong?

The invocation of the function is in IronPython code, the function is in C# code (an assembly which didn't change during this refactoring).

What sort of thing could generate this error?

EDIT: full IronPython traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\tab_manager.py", line 57, in add_chart_tab
    chart_tab = ChartTab(self.__main_window, self, tab_item, name, chart_descriptor)
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\chart_tab.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.__chart = Chart(self, self.__gui_cfg, self.__base_cfg, self.__chart_descriptor, self.__scroll_bar)
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\chart.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.update_topology(empty=False)
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\chart.py", line 93, in update_topology
    self.update_config()
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\chart.py", line 111, in update_config
    self.__global.chart_view = ChartView(self.__global)
  File "D:\Work\Framework\python\ide\chart_view.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.__spans = SpanUtil.compute_spans(time_series, gap_threshold)
TypeError: expected List[DataPoint], got List[DataPoint]
```

Comment: It would be fair easier to anser this question, if you post the code, even the exact error would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the error message right? Maybe it's saying "IList" instead of "List" for one of the params, perhaps?

Comment: I've added the full exception traceback. It's complicated to extract some code and post here - it spans both IronPython and C#, and I'm not sure I will even be able to reproduce this in a small piece of code since the error is indeed strange

Comment: I removed my answer because i did not read the question accuratly. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further debugging I managed to get a different error message from the code: `Unable to cast object of type 'List[DataPoint]' to 'List[DataPoint]'`

Searching for this yielded a couple of articles explaining the problem:
http://www.infinitec.de/post/2008/05/InvalidCastException-Unable-to-cast-object-of-Type-X-to-X.aspx
http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2010/02/16/137988.aspx

It turns out that the assembly containing `DataPoint` (from `List[DataPoint]`) it's loaded twice in my application from two different locations. The cause in my case is that when Visual Studio builds an assembly, it also copies all the other referenced assemblies next to the newly built one in the `bin` folder. But I also dynamically load one of the referenced assemblies from it's original build location.

Comment: Just want to note that I had the same problem. For example, in my project I had a reference to `"C:\\Something\\Something\\MyDLL.dll"`, and in IronPython I was loading `"C:/Something/Something/MyDLL.dll"`, causing it to load the same DLL twice. It **will** cause problems if they don't match, even if the path is essentially the same!

Answer (score 0):

May be an issue with the type resolution...use the complete type name (including the namespace). Some code sample might help!