# IronPython "Expected X, got X"

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get this .NET error - “TypeError: expected List[DataPoint], got List[DataPoint]”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596226/why-do-i-get-this-net-error-typeerror-expected-listdatapoint-got-listda)

Working on integrating Python scripting with my game engine, and I'm encountering a weird problem.

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append("D:/Development/C#/Bolt/Bolt/bin/x86/Debug")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Bolt.dll")
from Bolt import *

# this works
my_limit = Limit(-32, 32)

# this does not work
calling_object.location.x_limit = Limit(-32, 32)

# this does not work either
calling_object.location.x_limit = my_limit
```

I get this cryptic error when either of the non-working lines are present:

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.TypeErrorException: expected Limit, got Limit
```

Um. What?

calling_object is defined (elsewhere), as I can access and manipulate its location in other ways. I can clearly create an instance of the Bolt.Limit class, since it doesn't crash on the my_limit line.

Limit is just a normal-looking class. In C#, the Location class has a field of type Limit called "x_limit".

This should all fit together, but I don't know what's wrong. Limit isn't defined anywhere else. I can work around it for now, but I'd really like to know what the issue is.

Comment: This answer might help someone, in addition to the linked duplicate.
The solution was actually different than the other one. I was loading "D:/Development/C#/Bolt/Bolt/bin/x86/Debug/Bolt.dll", while earlier in the output window, I was loading: "D:\\Development\\C#\\Bolt\\Bolt\\bin\\x86\\Debug\\Bolt.dll".

Apparently, it didn't consider these to be the same file, and loaded them twice. Changing them to match solved the problem.