# How does IronPython pass an object to a C# method that expects an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ironpython, fix-protocol

I'm trying to call 
`public SocketInitiator(Application application, MessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings, LogFactory logFactory)`

Now the second argument is an interface:

```
namespace QuickFix
{
    public interface MessageStoreFactory
    {
        MessageStore Create(SessionID sessionID);
    }  
public class MemoryStoreFactory : MessageStoreFactory {...}
}
```

And I'm trying to pass it an instance of the interface:
`msf1=QuickFix.MemoryStoreFactory()`
`init=QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(osa, msf1, ss, screenlog)`
but I'm getting the rather unhelpful error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected MessageStoreFactory, got MemoryStoreFactory
```

Is there some way to identify to C#/CLR that the I have passed a Python instance of a class which implements the MessageStoreFactory instance?  Or is this some other, unrelated problem?

Comment: This answer argues that the specific manner in which dlls are loaded via AddReference makes a difference.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804885/kitchenpc-and-ironpython

Comment: If you implemented `MemoryStoreFactory` as shown in your sample and the constructor of `SocketInitiaton` takes a `MessageSoreFactory` it should just work. Whiche IronPython version are you using? Are you sure that there are not multiple classes/interfaces with the same name and you are getting some from the wrong namespace or assembly?

Comment: I think that I may have been adding a reference to the dll twice -- eventually got it to work. Wish there was some way to determine this.
IronPython 2.7.5